# HandlerThread safety in Android

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, android-handlerthread

Ok, this is a question I didn't think needed asking but either its the long hours or whatnot, but my mind is foggy so here it goes.

Creating a class with a HandlerThread, Looper, and Handler:

```
public class MyClass {
    //private volatile boolean mRunning   = false;
    private boolean mRunning              = false;
    private HandlerThread mHandlerThread  = null;
    private Handler mMessageHandler       = null;

    public static final int MESSAGE_START = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_STOP  = 2;

    public MyClass() {
        mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("com.test.myclass");
        mHandlerThread.start();
        mMessageHandler = new MessageHandler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    private class MessageHandler extends Handler {
        public MessageHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        private void start() {
            mRunning = true;
        }

        private void stop() {
            mRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            try {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MESSAGE_START:
                        start();
                        break;

                    case MESSAGE_STOP:
                        stop();
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid message: " + msg.what);
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                stop();
            }
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        if (isRunning()) {
            stop();
        }

        // PS: is this a good way to stop HandlerThead/Looper in API =< 17 ?
        if (mHandlerThread != null) {
            mHandlerThread.quit();
            mHandlerThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Should this be a synchronized method
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return mRunning;
        /**
         * Or should the variable be synchronized itself?
         * synchronized(mRunning) { return mRunning; }
         */

        // Or just use a semaphore?
    }

    public void start() {
        mMessageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_START);
    }

    public void stop() {
        mMessageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_STOP);
    }
}
```

So `mRunning` is accessed by both threads (main and looper). As such, the access should be synchronized. Which way would you choose? Making the variable volatile (so that both threads have up-to-date local values), making the `isRunning` method synchronized? Or accessing variable via `synchronized(mRunning){...}`?

Finally, implementation of `release` method, is that per standard? Or any other way you'd choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If contention for the lock is low, then synchronizing on a lock will cost about the same as a volatile access.  If conention is high, then the volatile version probably will perform better.

You can't do this though:

```
synchronized(mRunning) { ... }  //ERROR!
```

mRunning is a boolean expression.  You can't synchronize on a boolean value, you can only synchronize on an Object.

Comment: So from http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html, it seems that making mRunning volatile should be ok because the HandlerThread is the one that writes (in start/stop) and main thread is the one that reads, correct? Otherwise, if both were writing and reading, I'd use AtomicBoolean. Alternatively, I could `synchronize` start/stop/isRunning (while still keeping volatile mRunning so that threads stay in sync), correct? Synchronization would happen on the instance, similar to synchronize(this) and would lock the three methods.

Comment: The `get()` and `set()` methods of `AtomicBoolean` behave exactly like reading or writing a `volatile boolean`.  It becomes more useful than `volatile` if you can make use of its `getAndSet()` and/or `compareAndSet()` methods.  It's entirely up to you which one to use, but some people consider it good hygiene to always use AtomicWhatever instead of volatile whatever.